# How to add custom js in onepage checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I have to override the `onepage/review/item.phtml` file but I want to add js file in that.

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>cedapi/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

Already I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>product_designer/checkout_image.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add js in head of checkout page then use below code

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
          <reference name="head">
               <action method="addJs"><script>product_designer/checkout_image.js</script></action>
          </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want the js to be loaded when I click the 'Continue' button of 'Payment Information' tab. Please guide...

Comment: @jitendrakumar fir that you have to add js in your phtml then. because it loading the json response not whole layout.

Comment: so how to add js on perticular item.phtml file.

Comment: it is main `js` folder or `skin/js` folder?

Comment: main js folder.

Comment: use this in phtml `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS).'product_designer/checkout_image.js'?>"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47037/discussion-between-jitendra-kumar-and-qaisar-satti).